# Getting "control reaches end of non-void function" warning even when I've covered all cases

Tags: c++, multithreading

Why if I have two conditions while both returns the right type in a function as it should be, I am getting an alarm.

> control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

```
bool EtherTrafGen::isGenerator()
{
    if (multipacket) return par("destAddresses").stringValue()[0];
    else if (!multipacket) return par("destAddress").stringValue()[0];
}
```

What is the way to correct such an alarm?

Comment: Just use `else` instead of `else if`. Unless the 2 expressions behave in some odd way that they really aren't opposite. In which case, also provide an `else` (and rethink your design so that it makes sense to someone new to the project).

Comment: @BoBTFish Actually, in this case author even doesn't need to use `else` as the control flow will exit the function if `if` condition is satistied

Comment: i think there is no need to write `else if` because in the `if` of the first line if the condition is `true` , then on the `else if` it goes to be `false` and `vice verca`

Comment: even you don't need to write `else` too

Comment: @PaulR one is `destAdress` and the other is `destAddresses`. I am sorrz  it is confusing here but it make sense in the code.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I missed that those two strings were different...

Comment: Detecting that all path are covered is not a easy task in general case, you have to help the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though control can never reach

```
bool EtherTrafGen::isGenerator()
{
    if (multipacket) return par("destAddresses").stringValue()[0];
    else if (!multipacket) return par("destAddress").stringValue()[0];
    //here
}
```

The compiler can't know that (since it's an `else if`) and it warns you about potential undefined behaviour if it *is* reached (maybe another thread modifies `multipacket` after the first check etc). You can just add a default return value to satisfy the compiler:

```
bool EtherTrafGen::isGenerator()
{
    if (multipacket) return par("destAddresses").stringValue()[0];
    else if (!multipacket) return par("destAddress").stringValue()[0];
    return false;
}
```

Or just cut the whole `else if` since it's either `true` or `false`:

```
bool EtherTrafGen::isGenerator()
{
    if (multipacket) return par("destAddresses").stringValue()[0];
    return par("destAddress").stringValue()[0]; // multipacket must be false here anyway
}
```

Comment: `else` is redundant here. just return

Comment: @MRB Good observation.

Comment: why can't it reach //here?  I've got a 2nd thread that changes multipacket between the 2 checks ... now what?

Comment: @UKMonkey Without that provided information I'm just making the assumption the OP doesn't have such a thread.

Comment: @GillBates The compiler can't make that assumption though - hence the warning

Comment: @UKMonkey: There is no synchronization, so it would be UB to modify it in other thread.

Comment: @UKMonkey I'll add that

Comment: @Jarod42 The question does not say the type of multipacket, so maybe it's a `std::atomic_bool`. :P

Comment: multipacket is bool only I confirm :)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one case:

```
bool EtherTrafGen::isGenerator()
{
    if (multipacket) return par("destAddresses").stringValue()[0];
    else {
        if (!multipacket) return par("destAddress").stringValue()[0];
        else ???? <---- what should be done here
    }
}
```

Comment: You miss the OP's point: `multipacket` should evaluated to `true` or `false` only

Comment: You are correct, but he asked why that error occured, which means that he did not see that a case is not treated

Comment: The fact is that compiler doesn't detect that all cases are treated (which can be hard to detect in general case).

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by saying that the way you've structured your condition is quite exotic. You should just write it as:

```
if (multipacket) doX()
else doY()
```

It is true that the compiler should be smart enough to figure this case out, and not print an error.

However, your compiler isn't that smart. It's better not to have the warning, than to have it and *know* you're right.

---

Looking more broadly, there is a possibility that the code above is wrong, and it's not just the case that the compiler is not powerful enough in its analysis.

If the following code occurs in a multithreaded context, you might have rare threading issues where on the first access to multipacket you read a false, thus forcing you go to the second branch, and on the second access you read a true, thus forcing you go go out of the function without any return value. This case might happen if another thread modifies multipacket in between the two times it is read.

Granted, it's a small chance, as even if multipacket is changed by a separate thread, the modification might not be visible in that method immediately, because the value is in a register/cache/other temporary location that has been introduced by the compiler.

But why take the chance *and* write un-idiomatic code *and* have a warning on your hands?